# Annoying Invalid Syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am making a platforming game and I have just started it and I have come across a syntax error. The code is here:

```
import pygame, sys
from player import *
from constants import *

class Game():

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
        pygame.display.set_caption('GAME')

        self.font = pygame.font.Font('data/font/orecrusherexpanded.ttf', 50)

        self.black = (0, 0, 0)
        self.blue = (50, 60, 100)

        self.player = Player(250, 250)

    def run(self):

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        RUNNING = True

        while RUNNING:

            for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()

            fps = 60
            self.screen.fill(self.blue)

            self.player_move()
            self.player.update()
            self.player.handle_events(event)
            self.player.render(self.screen)
            self.screen.blit(self.font.render("FPS: " + str(clock.get_fps()), 1, (255, 0, 0), (0,0))

            clock.tick(fps)

            pygame.display.flip()

    def player_move(self):

        self.player.rect.x += self.player.velX
        self.player.rect.y += self.player.velY

Game().run()
```

Where it says clock.tick(fps) When I run the program the error highlights clock and pops up saying Invalid Syntax! Thanks for any help.

Comment: You are missing a closing ')' at the end of the line just above this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually on the line previous to `clock.tick(fps)`.

```
self.screen.blit(self.font.render("FPS: " + str(clock.get_fps()), 1, (255, 0, 0), (0,0))
```

You don't have enough closing parentheses on this line. It should probably be:

```
self.screen.blit(self.font.render("FPS: " + str(clock.get_fps()), 1, (255, 0, 0), (0,0)))
```

Comment: Ahh damn sorry about that. Didn't notice that thanks for pointing out my error.